# call external loaded java class

Tags: java

I loaded an external java class to my project, that class is to send a voice to clients(I called it sender.java), So I want to call that class or run it from the main frame of my project using a button. How can I do that? let's say the button variable name is "start broadcasting"? please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate this class (assuming you're not using a static method) and then invoke a method on it. e.g.

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
obj.myMethod();
```

You may need to import it into your namespace e.g.

```
import com.yourpackage.MyObject;
...
```

then the above.

Comment: mrshaheen.ye@gmail.com 
Mr.Brian can you please send me an email so I can get your email address to send you the code it is a very small issue, please...